# R, argument missing with no default

Tags: r, function, arguments

I build a function, and it works when one of the arguments is hardcoded in the code, but as soon as I include it in the list of arguments I get an error .... simple I realise but is stumping me!

```
## load necessary libraries
library(gsubfn)

## number of days
days <- 5

AdDayFun <- function (inarray) {
    gsubfn("^\\D*\\d+\\D*\\K(\\d+)",
           ~ ifelse(as.numeric(x) < 5,
                    sprintf("%02d",as.numeric(x)+1),
                    "00"),
           inarray,
           perl=TRUE
           )
}

## initial population 
pop <- matrix(c("a-00-04","a-00-00","a-00-00", "dead", "a-00-00"), nrow =1)
pop




pop <- rbind(pop, AdDayFun(pop[nrow(pop), ]))
pop
```

This all works fine, until I change the function to require two arguments, and then get error?

```
AdDayFun <- function (inarray, nummax) {
    gsubfn("^\\D*\\d+\\D*\\K(\\d+)",
           ~ ifelse(as.numeric(x) < nummax,
                    sprintf("%02d",as.numeric(x)+1),
                    "00"),
           inarray,
           perl=TRUE
           )
}

(AdDayFun(pop[nrow(pop), ], 7))
```

Error as such:
Error in ifelse(as.numeric(x) < nummax, sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x) +  : 
  argument "nummax" is missing, with no default

Comment: Where does the `x` in your function come from?

Comment: I think with the gsubfn, it comes from the array variable that I have called "inarray".  Tx. J

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to get confused here. You are writing a function,`AdDayFun`, that wraps another function, `gsubfn`, which itself takes an unnamed function or formula as an argument.

What we would like to be able to do is allow `nummax` to be passed as a parameter to the unnamed function. However, there doesn't seem to be a built-in method for passing arbitrary parameters to this function.

However, since you are wrapping `gsubfn` in your own function, there is a workaround, which is to pre-define the unnamed function a second parameter that has `nummax` as a default value:

```r
AdDayFun <- function (inarray, nummax) 
{
  f <- function(x, y = nummax)
  {
    ifelse(as.numeric(x) < y, sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x) + 1), "00")
  }

  gsubfn("^\\D*\\d+\\D*\\K(\\d+)", f, inarray, perl = TRUE)
}
```

Which gives the following result:

```
a <- AdDayFun(pop[nrow(pop),], 5)
a
#> [1] "a-00-05" "a-00-01" "a-00-01" "dead"    "a-00-01"

a <- AdDayFun(a, 7)
a
#> [1] "a-00-06" "a-00-02" "a-00-02" "dead"    "a-00-02"

a <- AdDayFun(a, 5)
a
#> [1] "a-00-00" "a-00-03" "a-00-03" "dead"    "a-00-03"
```

Comment: Thx Allan, close but for me it, the AdDayFun produces results that iterate between 00 and 01, no matter what value is set for the nummax.  Is it something in the regex selection?

Comment: @JimMaas sorry - I think I had misinterpreted what `backref` meant in the documents. I have substantially changed my answer and it should be much simpler to use now anyway.